# Increase the size of a np.array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, reshape

I ran a conv1D on a X matrix of shape (2000, 20, 28) for batch size of 2000, 20 time steps and 28 features.
I would like to move forward to a conv2D CNN and increase the dimensionality of my matrix to (2000, 20, 28, 10) having 10 elements for which I can build a (2000, 20, 28) X matrix. Similarly, I want to get a y array of size (2000, 10) i.e. 5 times the y array of size (2000, ) that I used to get for LSTM and Conv1D networks.

The code I used to create the 20 time-steps from input dataX, dataY, was

```
def LSTM_create_dataset(dataX, dataY, seq_length, step):
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(0, len(dataX) - seq_length, step):
        v = dataX.iloc[i:(i + seq_length)].values
        Xs.append(v)
        ys.append(dataY.iloc[i + seq_length])
    return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)
```

I use this function within the loop I prepared to create the data of my conv2D NN :

```
for ric in rics:
    dataX, dataY = get_model_data(dbInput, dbList, ric, horiz, drop_rows, triggerUp1, triggerLoss, triggerUp2 = 0)
    dataX = get_model_cleanXset(dataX, trigger)                             # Clean X matrix for insufficient data
    Xs, ys = LSTM_create_dataset(dataX, dataY, seq_length, step)        # slide over seq_length for a 3D matrix
    Xconv.append(Xs)
    yconv.append(ys)
    Xconv.append(Xs)
    yconv.append(ys)
```

I obtain a (10, 2000, 20, 28) Xconv matrix instead of the (2000, 20, 28, 10) targeted output matrix X and a (10, 2000) matrix y instead of the targeted (2000, 10).
I know that I can easily reshape yconv with `yconv = np.reshape(yconv, (2000, 5))`. But the reshape function for Xconv `Xconv = np.reshape(Xconv, (2000, 20, 28, 10))` seems hazardous as I cannot vizualize output and even erroneous.
How could I do it safely (or could you confirm my first attempt ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix for y has shape **(10, 2000)** then you will not be able to shape it to your desired **(2000,5)**. I've demonstrated this below.

```
# create array of same shape as your original y
arr_1 = np.arange(0,2000*10).reshape(10,2000) 
print(arr_1.shape) # returns (10,2000)
arr_1 = arr_1.reshape(2000,5)
```

This returns the following error message as it is critical that the dimensions of the before and after shapes must match.

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 20000 into shape (2000,5)
```

I do not fully understand the statement that you cannot visualise the output - you could manually check that the `reshape` function had done so correctly if you wished, for your dataset (or a small part of it to confirm that the function is working effectively) using print statements, as below - by comparing the output to your original data and what you expect the data to look like afterwards.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(0,2000) 
arr = arr.reshape(20,10,10,1) # reshape array to shape (20, 10, 10, 1)

# these statements let you examine the array contents at varying depths
print(arr[0][0][0])
print(arr[0][0])
```

Comment: Indeed. I meant (2000, 10), that is achieved with reshape...